# Python 3.6 on Windows 7 x64 - Installation Fail 0x80070660

Tags: python-3.6, windows-7-x64

I'm trying to install python 3.6.6 on my windows 7 sp1 with all the updates. So, than I got error 0x80070660. I looked at the log file, tried to change the path to the folder of temporary files, but all is useless. Tell me what else can be done to fix the error?

[image: e]

Comment: Would you mind translating the error message in english, please? This is an english speaking site. Also, please post the error message as text, not as picture. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Decided! It turns out it was simple. Once I removed the "Installer" folder from the Windows directory to free up space. Now I've re-created this directory and the error has disappeared.